# Glibc issue using g++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, glibc

I have a problem, i'm compiling my C++ app in Linux machine. Then i move executable to other machine, but i have an error:

```
./server: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by ./server)
```

How can i fix it? Without recompiling on second machine where this error happens (it is my client machine)

Compile command:

```
g++  -o server  test.cpp server.cpp ... -lboost_system -lboost_thread -std=c++0x
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app is using glibc-2.7 library, and app can not find it on other machine.  It probably have older version of this library. You have following options:

- Upgrade this library on target host
- Link you app against older library version
- Use static linking
- Ship library together with app

---

How statically link to just one library:

```
gcc main.c mylibrary.a -o main
```

Note that most distros do not install static libraries by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you help me how to compile with static linking of glibc, but other libs should be still dynamically linked

Comment: I would suggest to install, in a `chroot`-ed environment, on your development machine the same system as your target machine. Then you can link dynamically, which is much better.

Answer (score 1):

There are three choices:

1. compile on the original machine with `-static` given to the compiler, which will include the relevant libraries in your binary [and possibly give you a warning or two about "this may not work right"]
2. compile the code on the new machine.
3. Install the correct version of library on the target machine.

I tend to use option 1 most of the time, but have used all three at various points.